iText7 C# autocleanup no redaction some PDFs
hoping for some guidance.  I'm running into issues w/the autosweepcleanup.  I am running into PDFs in which the nothing is being redacted, despite matching my regex patterns.  There appears to be no protection on the document and I am able to parse the content.
in debugging, I've tried redacting the explicit string match -nothing.. writing to console when the match is found.. I can confirm content capture.
On other PDFs, code works well -so I'm stumped.
I don't believe there's a method to determine "IF" a redaction was applied or match found (native to the autosweepcleanup.
Unfortunately, due to the nature of the PDFs, I cannot provide them here.
Here are my regex patterns:
string Pattern1 = @"(?<!\d)(\d{11,}(?=\d{4}(?!\d))|(\d{4}[- ]?){3}\d{3}(?=\d{4}(?!\d))|(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9}|\d{3}\d{2}\d{4})(?=\d{4}(?!\d)))";
string Pattern2 = @"\b\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}(?=\b|\s|$)";
string Pattern3 = @"\b\d{4}[- ]?\d{4}[- ]?\d{4}\b"; //looks for 12 chars, with change in font/face for last 12
string Pattern4 = @"(?<!\d)(\d{3}-\d{2}|\d{5}|\d{3} \d{2})(?=\d{4}(?!\d))";
string Pattern5 = @"\b\d{14,}(?=\D|$)";
string Pattern6 = @"(?<=\b\d{12})\d+";
I'm applying these are part of a cleanupstrategy.
I welcome any feedback, thank you in advance.
On other PDFs, code works well -so I'm stumped.
I don't believe there's a method to determine "IF" a redaction was applied or match found (native to the autocleanup.
I hoped for reliable redaction
Update: I found this older post -wondering this this is issue persists?  it aligns with my experience/problem PDFs and location of the redaction target (end of string)
iText PDFSweep RegexBasedCleanupStrategy not work in some case

"Unfortunately, due to the nature of the PDFs, I cannot provide them here." - How then do you expect others to understand what happens?

So interesting.. your example PDF generates a new, previously unseen exception.
Redaction exception for Abracadabra2.pdf.  Exception: Invalid PDF. There is no media box attribute for page or its parents.

@mkl -through inquiry, where needed, challenging me if needed.  I'll share code where permissible.

I've compared working and non PDFs, in terms of content, I see no differences *shrug.  you have my regex above.. below is super simple call of cleanup.  This works for most, but again my exception count is sizeable.  I don't believe it to be a PDF protection issue, as I'm not overwriting the existing.  I am copying content, redacting, saving to a new.

List cleanupStrategies = new List
{
new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(new Regex(Pattern1, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)).SetRedactionColor(ColorConstants.BLACK),
new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(new Regex(Pattern2, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)).SetRedactionColor(ColorConstants.BLACK),
//remaining patterns
// Add more strategies for additional patterns
};
// Apply all cleanup strategies
foreach (var cleanupStrategy in cleanupStrategies)
{
PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp(pdf, cleanupStrategy);
}
pdf.Close();

"through inquiry, where needed, challenging me if needed. I'll share code where permissible." - you say that in debugging you found that the regular expressions did not find the text in question. Consequentially, you should have checked what text iText does recognize in your document. Have you? It's possible your document does not contain the information necessary for normal text extraction or even contains misleading, incorrect information.

Apologies, I did not mean to say the regex couldn't be found.  I added a little check, since removed that just wrote to the console on what page the pattern match was found.  In content review, pattern is also there.. pasting into a text editor, I find the crlf chars.
I pivoted and started trying to replace text in place swapping credit card matches for a string phrase..again matches were found, text is being overlayed, but not replacing the pre-existing text.  I'm scratching my head.  Again, for a number of other batches, all code, as-is works great.

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but in close review, some characters while appearing as readable text, ex: "If you would like information" are actually as so in the PDF: If youwouldlikeinformation. -perhaps nothing, just pointing out differences.
Also, this looks to be mixed content, first couple of pages are searchable text, but latter pages are not -appear to be images.  Again, not sure if impactful as I can confirm pattern matches are found.. just sharing as I learn.

oookay, so I opened the source PDF in adobe (apologies I hadn't done that earlier).. there are no less than hundreds of layers in this PDF.. good gosh.  At any rate, I'm toying w/code to flatten layers, hopeful.. prayerful that will help -no luck to this point, welcome any feedback.. maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I would guess that you have lots of scanned page bitmaps there with OCR'ed text drawn as invisible text thereover or thereunder. This is not optimal for iText PDFSweep which tries to remove the text and clear the bitmap image areas but does not support all bitmap image variants.

Dang.. any known alternatives, for use in c#?  -my attempts to "flatten" the layers haven't been successful, yet.
